# MySQL Server Error-Access Denied

Tags: mysql, localhost, access-denied

I installed mysql to run a project on my local host. Everything went on normally and I opened my web-application project locally. Now when I try to access my project it gives me "This webpage is not available".

So I wanted to test if MySQL server is running. So I followed this tutorial:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-testing.html

This is what I get:

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqlshow"
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqlshow: Access denie
ser 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)


C:\>"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqlshow" -u root
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqlshow: Access denie
ser 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)


C:\>"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqladmin" versio
s proc
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqladmin: connect to
at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

C:\>"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysql" test
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using pass
O)
```

What is the problem?

UPDATE: I tried this:

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqlshow" -u root -p
Enter password: ********
+--------------------+
|     Databases      |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| fedena_ultimate    |
| mysql              |
| test               |
+--------------------+

C:\>"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqladmin" version statu
s proc
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqladmin: connect to server
at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

So should I set a password for user ODBC? And how?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are running sql in administrator mode?

and try resetting the authentication values :-

> mysql --host=localhost --user=**username** --password